# gradle always use repo.maven.apache.org even if i point custom repositories

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

From my network i can't access `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` repository,  so i have to point proxy  like `http://nexus.companyproxy.com:8099/nexus/content/groups/public`
My configuration contains only this

```
repositories { 
   maven("http://nexus.companyproxy.com:8099/nexus/content/groups/public") 
}
```

but when I run gradle with **—debug** I see many errors Caused by:

```
org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.41/kotlin-c...
```

After this unsuccessful requests it download dependency from proper repository (proxy), but why i can't avoid such problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if is thing of the syntax: 
```repositories {
    maven {
      url 'http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2'
    }
}
``` That's the way used in the docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.RepositoryHandlerExtensions
`fun RepositoryHandler.maven(url: Any) =
         maven { it.setUrl(url) }`
So my syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your question is old, but I had the same issue last days and google redirect me to your post.

In the logs I can see that Gradle uses my local artifactory, then it switches to the default remote repository:

```
15:04:47  2022-02-17T15:04:47.572+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Download http://artifactory.mycompany.local/artifactory/maven/org/mockito/mockito-core/maven-metadata.xml'
15:04:47  2022-02-17T15:04:47.572+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Download http://artifactory.mycompany.local/artifactory/maven/org/mockito/mockito-core/maven-metadata.xml' completed
15:04:47  2022-02-17T15:04:47.576+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.maven.MavenMetadataLoader] parsing maven-metadata: org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultLocallyAvailableExternalResource@5568cd26
15:04:47  2022-02-17T15:04:47.585+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-core/maven-metadata.xml
...
15:06:24  2022-02-17T15:06:21.731+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.12.215] failed: connect timed out
...
15:06:24  2022-02-17T15:06:21.731+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 2m 35s
```

I suppose that Gradle tries to list the versions from all repositories to define the latest version '2.+'. However the connection to the `repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` repository is not possible, so the build fails in my case.

My solution was to to change the version from `'2.+'` to a fixed version in the  `build.gradle` file, i.e.:

```
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.+'
```

to

```
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.28.2'
```